# How to create a scroll able layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I am designing a screen for mobile devices (android), i wanted to display multiple text boxes and buttons on a screen.

Would someone please guide me how can i a make my screen scroll able so that all the text boxes and buttons can be created and viewed on same page.

I tried searching different postings also tried to find any property but couldn't get success.

Regards,
Gul

Answer (score 0):

Use a  [`ScrollView`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qwoYq.gif). When he contents of a ScrollView cannot fit the allocated height it will become scrollable.

**Note** that a ScrollView can only contain a single direct child element so if you need multiple things to be scrollable, you need to wrap that content into a layout.

Here is an example

```
<ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_long"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="@string/really_long_string" >
        </TextView>

        <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_act"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="View" >
        </Button>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use ScrollView as the main parent layout. If you don't give the scrollview, then you can't scroll the page.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <LinearLayout

        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Button
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button 1" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button 2" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button 3" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button 4" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button 5" />

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioButton2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="RadioButton 1" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioButton1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="RadioButton 2" />

        <ToggleButton
            android:id="@+id/toggleButton1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="ToggleButton" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button 6" />

        <SeekBar
            android:id="@+id/seekBar1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button 7" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button 8" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="CheckBox" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button 9" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button 10" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button 11" />
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```